# Go out of fashion or go out of trend?

Tags: vocabulary

I am practicing for my FCE exam and I have found this expression in the "use of english" part. According to the book, the right answer is **go out of fashion** but I can´t understand the difference between them. 
I would appreciate that someone clear my ideas.
Thank you all

> Although expensevely decorated tables remained popular into 19th
>   century, the idea then **went out of** ............ and was largely
>   forgotten.

The options are: a) fashion b) custom c) habit d) trend

Comment: Fashion and trend are synonyms https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/thesaurus/trend you got to include some context

Comment: Well done. I think that you've got a pair of typos. (1) "right answer is get out" should be "right answer is go out of fashion" and (2) "then wen out" should be "then went out".

Comment: As a native English speaker, "Went out of fashion" is a phrase I have heard while "Went out of trend" is not. I can't give a good reason, but I do agree with the book about *which one* is the correct answer.

Comment: This exam question isn't about rules of grammar, it's about a common expression. From a syntactic point of view, *out of fashion* is the same construction as *out of trend*. (It is a fashion, it is a trend . . .) However, for whatever reason of social adoption, only *out of fashion* is actually used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been thinking about this question for a while ... Let me compile my thoughts and the comments offered by native English speakers.

According to Cambridge Dictionary

[**fashion**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/fashion)

> a style that is popular at a particular time, especially in clothes,
>   hair, make-up, etc.

**[trend](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/es/diccionario/ingles/trend)**

> a new development in clothing, make-up, etc.:

and

> **on trend**: fashionable

---

According to Oxford Thesaurus

[**trend**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/thesaurus/trend)

> SYNONYMS
>
> **fashion**, vogue, style, mode, craze, mania, rage

---

According to The Free Dictionary

**[go out of fashion](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/go+out+of+fashion)** and go out of style

> to become unfashionable; to become obsolete

---

So gramatically and semantically, it may be correct to infer that you can use **go out of fashion** and **go out of trend** indistinctly. **But the second one is not used**.

Let me establish a paralelism with the Spanish language.
We've got two words: **moda** (fashion) and **tendencia** (trend) whose meanings are equivalent to the English ones.

We say that **algo ha pasado de moda** (something has **went out of fashion**) but we don't say that **algo ha pasado de tendencia** (something has **went out of trend**).

Answer (score 2):

*Fashion* is the only word of all the options that collocates with "went out of ____". (This comes from my experience as a native speaker, and it's backed up by a quick search of [the Corpus of Contemporary American English](https://corpus.byu.edu/coca/) for `went out of *`.)

You can find "out of fashion" in plenty of dictionaries. It has two meanings, with the relevant one here being #2:

> 1. of clothing : no longer generally worn by people • *Those ruffled blouses went out of fashion years ago.*
> 2. of a style of something, a way of behaving, etc. : no longer generally liked by people : unpopular • *Her theories have fallen out of fashion.*
>
> <sub>[Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/out%20of%20fashion)</sub>